# Showing Servlet data in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is my first attempt to create a Java Web app and I’m having some difficult to show data from a servlet into a JSP page.

```
The class 

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Atleta {
    private int socio;
    private String nome;
    private String sexo;



    public void setSocio(int soc){
        this.socio=soc;
    }
    public long getSocio(){
        return(this.socio);
    }

    public void setNome(String nom){
        this.nome=nom;
    }
    public String getNome(){
        return (this.nome);
    }

    public void setSexo(String sex){
        this.sexo=sex;
    }
    public String getSexo(){
        return (this.sexo);
    }

    public Atleta (ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException
    {
        this.socio = resultSet.getInt("socio");
        this.nome = resultSet.getString("nome");
        this.sexo = resultSet.getString("sexo");

    }
}



The servlet

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import appClass.Atleta;
import dbconn.dbconn;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String qryStr = "";
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            //res.setContentType("text/html");
            //PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Connection conn = null;
               //using movie_resolved view
            try{
              // Get a Connection to the database
             conn = dbconn.getConnection();
             // Create a Statement object
              stmt = conn.createStatement();
              // Execute an SQL query, get a ResultSet
              qryStr = "SELECT socio, nome, sexo from atletas";

              rs = stmt.executeQuery(qryStr); 

             if (rs.next())
              {

                Atleta atleta = new Atleta (rs);
                atleta.setSocio(rs.getInt("socio"));
                atleta.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                atleta.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                request.setAttribute("atleta", atleta);
                RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("atleta.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);
              }

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
             out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
            }

              try {
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
              }
              catch (SQLException ignored) { }
           }
          }

The JSP

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" import="java.util.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Lista de Atletas!</h2>

        <table border="1">


        <TR>
            <TD>Socio: </TD>
            <TD>${atleta.socio}</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>Lastname: </TD>
            <TD>${atleta.nome}</TD>
        </TR>
         <TR>
            <TD>Firstname: </TD>
            <TD>${atleta.sexo}</TD>
        </TR>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong or if there is anything missing.

Thanks and regards,

Joaquim

Comment: @Joaquim How many rows are there in table? Also you seem to be using EL. Make sure you have setup for that. What output are you getting? or any errors?

Comment: so far i only get the table. no data and no errors!

Comment: the table has 156 rows. When you to check the EL setup what do you mean exactly?

Comment: this is part of the web.xml file                                                                            <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>atleta.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

Comment: are you calling JSP directly or through servlet. and according to your code it will only show one row data at a time.

Comment: I believe my problem its solve. I remove the "Atleta" class put the servlet on the default package, before was on a folder called 'servlet' and create an array to store data and create a new jsp to see the data using 'request.getAttribute.